# npm-check-updates groupFunction is not working

Tags: npm-check-updates

npm-check-updates groupFunction  is not working, my code below.

```
console.log("groupFunction default:", defaultGroup); is not logged.
```

ref: https://github.com/raineorshine/npm-check-updates#groupfunction

```
function groupFunction (name, defaultGroup, currentSpec, upgradedSpec, upgradedVersion){
  console.log("groupFunction default:", defaultGroup);
  return defaultGroup
}

ncu.run({
  packageFile: '../package.json',
  groupFunction:groupFunction,
  upgrade: false,
  color:true
}).then((upgraded) => {
  console.log('dependencies to upgrade:', upgraded);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```